# Assembly read byte from STDIN directly into register

Tags: nasm, stdin, cpu-registers

In x64 NASM, if I wanted to read one character from STDIN into an 8-bit register, the only method I know is this:

```
xor rax, rax
xor rdi, rdi
mov rsi, buffer
mov rdx, 1
syscall
mov al, byte [buffer]
```

Would it be possible to read the character directly into the register, without using a buffer? (I am using Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Look through the syscalls to see if one does what you want. U didn't say what operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you want to keep in mind is that a keypress does not necessarily equate to one byte. As an example, function keys can return up to 5 bytes. This method doesn't require a specially allocated buffer, but conceptually, space on stack could be considered a buffer.

> See comment below **edi, 8** should be **edx, 8**

```
    mov     edi, 8                ; Size of one QWORD
    push    rax                   ; Could be any register, we just need 8 bytes
    mov     rsi, rsp
    xor     edi, edi              ; Essentially STDIN
    mov     eax, edi              ; SYS_READ
    syscall
    pop     rax                   ; Bytes
```

If you pressed one of the 96 keys from space (20H) to tilde (7FH) then a your result will be returned in AL. However if AL = 27 (1BH) then the remaining bits (08-3F) will have the other relevant data.

I use this procedure to accept a single keystroke without echo and the need to press return to accept entry.

```
; =============================================================================
; Accept a single key press from operator and return the result that may be
; up to 5 bytes in length.

;    LEAVE: RAX = Byte[s] returned by SYS_READ
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  %define   c_lflag     rdx + 12
  %define      keys     rbp +  8
  %define      MASK     ICANON | ECHO

  STK_SIZE  equ 56              ; Room for 36 byte termios structure

  QueryKey:

        xor     eax, eax
        push    rax             ; This is where result will be stored.

        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, STK_SIZE

        push    r11             ; Modified by SYSCALL
        push    rbx
        push    rdx
        push    rcx
        push    rdi
        push    rsi             ; With size of 56, stack is now QWORD aligned

        mov     edi, eax        ; Equivalent to setting EDI to STDOUT
        mov     esi, TCGETS
        lea     rdx, [rbp-STK_SIZE] ; Points to TERMIOS buffer on stack
        mov      al, sys_ioctl
        syscall

        lea     rbx, [c_lflag]
        and     byte [rbx], ~(MASK)
        inc     esi                 ; RSI = TCPUTS
        push    rsi
        mov      al, sys_ioctl
        push    rax
        syscall

   ; Wait for keypress from operator.

        lea     rsi, [keys]         ; Set buffer for input
        push    rdx
        mov     edx, 8              ; Read QWORD bytes max
        mov      al, sys_read
        syscall

        pop     rdx                 ; Points back to TERMIOS
        pop     rax
        pop     rsi                 ; TCPUTS again
        or      byte [rbx], MASK
        syscall

        pop     rsi
        pop     rdi
        pop     rcx
        pop     rdx
        pop     rbx
        pop     r11

        leave
        pop        rax              ; Return up to 8 characters
        ret
```

Comment: `mov edi, 8` in your first example is useless, because you're overwriting edi with the `xor` zeroing.